# Eclipse crashes when attempting to "Sign in to Google" on Linux using two-factor authentication

Tags: linux, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-eclipse-plugin

First, apologies if StackOverflow is the wrong Q&A site for this question, I'm happy to move it to another if needed...

Eclipse crashes whenever I try to sign in to my Google account in the plugin (the link in bottom left of eclipse). I can enter my email and password ok, it then loads the page for my verification code (because I use [Google's two-factor authentication](http://googleblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/advanced-sign-in-security-for-your.html)). After I submit my verification code, eclipse completely crashes and disappears from my desktop.

Any ideas?

**Environment**: Fresh install of the following:

1. Mint Linux 13
2. I have two-factor authentication enabled on my Google (apps) account.
3. Eclipse Indigo
4. Google plugin for eclipse

**Update - 2012/06/27**
This is the output in the console:

```
$ eclipse
12:26:50.336 [org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler] INFO  org.mortbay.log - Logging to Logger[org.mortbay.log] via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x00b16e62, pid=3853, tid=3077970176
#
# JRE version: 6.0_24-b24
# Java VM: OpenJDK Client VM (20.0-b12 mixed mode, sharing linux-x86 )
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.11.1
# Distribution: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, package 6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu3
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00b16e62
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/matt/gitrepos/OddPrints/hs_err_pid3853.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Or **if you're really keen** the [full log is here](http://pastebin.com/Jn7mSxHC).

**Update - 2012/06/28**

As suggested by @jpe, I tried updating my default browser in the eclipse config to "mozilla". This just kicked up an error saying it couldn't launch a browser and so was going to launch one externally for my lo log into. I t also gave me a box to enter the verification code. I did this but after entering the verification code it bombed out with error 400. Here is the tail of the eclipse log:

```
!ENTRY com.google.gdt.eclipse.login 4 0 2012-06-28 14:53:36.043
!MESSAGE Could not sign in. Make sure that you entered the correct verification code.
!STACK 0
com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:380)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenRequest.executeUnparsed(AccessTokenRequest.java:457)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenRequest.execute(AccessTokenRequest.java:473)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.GoogleLogin.logIn(GoogleLogin.java:376)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.GoogleLogin.logIn(GoogleLogin.java:312)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.ui.LoginTrimContribution$1.mouseUp(LoginTrimContribution.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3588)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3209)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Comment: First, it worked for me on my mac. Can you run eclipse from your command line and see the output from the eclipse when this happens?

Comment: Hi @TakashiMatsuo, I've added the console output and log file. Could it be that I'm using OpenJDK?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you stumbled upon the [Incompatibility between WebKit and XULRunner's sqlite Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349837). A quote from the bug report: "The only way to ensure that this error does not happen is to [set the org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType property](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserspecifydefault)."

So the above fixed the Eclipse crash as was hinted by an editet of the question. Now you seem to have stumbled upon a Google App Engine issue, perhaps this [one](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5971). People say that if the time is significantly inaccurate in your computer, appengine will refuse login.

It would help if you could test the login you attempt from Eclipse using some other method from your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, at least a workaround.
I have the same problem, Ubuntu 10.04 x64, eclipse Juno on a Virtual Machine..
So, instead of using the button Sign in to Google Account in the lower end of the Eclipse window, just use the option from the G icon on the top toolbar, where you can create new projects, update etc with GWT. So: press `Deploy to App Engine` and sign in before doing anything. Then, you'll be logged in. Then again, Eclipse will crash, but at least the login will remain, so after you restart Eclipse, you should have your account synched with your IDE. Hope it helps, it worked for me.